# Long Press (python) record button and play voice

Tags: python, class, long-press

I have a button, and i am trying to fire two actions in one button. I
I do not know, to use long press call a class speak

```
try several ways but none please help me

def speak():
tts.save(filename)
   playsound.playsound(filename)
speak()
name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element)
TouchAction.long_press(name, duration=3000).perform().release()???
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
def do_two_things():
    do_this()
    do_that_too()

def do_this():
    # do this thing

def do_that_too():
    # yes, do that too!

...
TouchAction.long_press(name, duration=3000).do_two_things()
```